# GDK: setting event mask on root window to intercept map events is not working

Tags: xlib, window-managers, gdk, xcb

I recently wanted to start developing a window manager to get to know the X Server better. My choice initially fell on raw XCB to talk with the X Server, but it was quickly dropped when I discovered GDK, which seems to be a high-level wrapper around Xlib (if I'm not mistaken).

I started rewriting the super convoluted code I wrote in XCB to like 20-30 lines in total thanks to GDK, but then I hit a rock.
I want to get all the map requests to the root from every new window so that I can setup and draw the frame and perform the reparenting for them before effectively granting them visibility, but it seems like I cannot get it to work. I tried with the structure/subsctructure event mask but nothing happens (which is strange, because it for example works for the button press event).

I hope I didn't mistake GDK as a library through which developing a window manager is made easier.

The whole code (not much really) [can be found here](https://github.com/luzzif/bruh-wm) (the project's name is a bit silly I know).

Comment: I don't think you can use the X11 abstraction in GDK to write a window manager, but I am not sure about this. Wikipedia says GDK means "GIMP Drawing Kit", which already hints at where this comes from.

Comment: @UliSchlachter yeah, I don't really get some of the namings of these libraries. GTK also means GIMP toolkit, but while originally developed specifically for GIMP itself, it has then evolved to be a general-purpose UI toolkit. I thought the same happened with GDK, which seems to be very general-purpose (in fact, it is used by GTK internally).